# What does "yet" mean in this news article?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What does "yet" mean in this sentence below?

> The Biden administration’s study of the leak is ongoing, but private
> experts told CNN it offers some of the clearest public evidence **yet** of
> how they believe China’s powerful security agencies outsource hacking
> operations to tech firms to target victims around the world.

This sentence is from this news. https://edition.cnn.com/2024/02/22/politics/leaked-documents-tech-firm-chinese-hacking/index.html

---

I think yet often means either of these.

1. I haven't left home yet.
2. He's overweight, and yet he's attractive. (This meaning is similar to "but".)

However, these two meanings do not seem to match the sentence.

Comment: Meaning 1 - _until the present or a specified or implied time_ as any good dictionary will tell you.

Comment: It means "up until the present time".  Yet has many meanings in English, and the meaning depends on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Biden administration’s study of the leak is ongoing, but private experts told CNN it offers some of the clearest public evidence [***so far***] of how they believe China’s powerful security agencies outsource hacking operations to tech firms to target victims around the world. 
>  https://edition.cnn.com/2024/02/22/politics/leaked-documents-tech-firm-chinese-hacking/index.html

It means that *of all the public evidence that private experts have studied* regarding China possibly outsourcing hacking operations to tech firms to target victims around the world, *this leak has been the most incriminating evidence* they have had *up to this point in time*.

A simple search online with a dictionary tells us:

> 2 a (1) : up to now : so far 
> *hasn't done much yet* 
> —often used to imply the negative of a following infinitive 
> *have yet to win a game* 
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet

Hope this helps!